# USB devices not working if I solder them through wires

Tags: usb

When I'm trying to connect a USB device like a USB WiFi dongle or Pendrive with a homegrown USB breakout by soldering 4 wires to them, it's just not working.

I'm running Ubuntu and getting errors like this,

```
hub 1-1:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 3
```

Above line is not the exact same error message, I can post them if needed.

But low speed USB devices like a USB AVR programmer is working fine.

The `ehci-pci` kernel driver is being used for both high-speed and low-speed USB devices.

So what's the problem with high-speed devices ? Is there any way to fix this problem ? Probably extra capacitance and inductance from the DIY breakout is violating high-speed USB specification, am I right ?

Comment: That and the impedance mismatch too yes

Comment: Thanks ! And what kind of impedance mismatch ? If you can make it a bit clear please.

Comment: Google "transmission line impedance". USB D+/D- lines should be a twisted pair of the correct impedance.

Comment: Thanks  Tom Carpenter, I'm using cat5 cables twisted pairs for D+ and D-, is it causing some impedance mismatch ? I also presume I have to solder the twisted pair as close as possible to the USB male connector, am I right ?

Comment: Might be worth posting a photo of your setup. USB is 90Ohm differential while Ethernet is 100Ohm. Might work, might not, depends how long the cable is and how sensitive the device is.

Comment: *I'm using cat5 cables twisted pairs* That cat5 is for **Ethernet** which is not **USB**. How **long** is your cable ?  If it is up to 20 cm it *might* just work. For a longer distance: forget about that, you **must** use USB cable. Note how in a USB cable the datalines are **NOT** twisted !

Comment: @FakeMoustache what USB cables have you been using? USB 2.0 data lines are as per the spec twisted for high and full speed. See [Section 6.3, P87 of the spec (page 5 in linked document)](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/ecn1.pdf)

Comment: @TomCarpenter OK, I stand corrected, indeed above 12 MBit the pairs are twisted but only one twist every 60mm, a lot **less** than ethernet so that's probably why I didn't notice that twisting.

Comment: @ FakeMoustache, So it will be better if I rewind the data line with less turns/m ?

Answer (score 2):

> Probably extra capacitance and inductance from the DIY breakout is violating high-speed USB specification

Nope. The problem is *impedance*. USB 2.0 is high frequency enough to have signal refections at any point with significant impedance mismatch - and your breakout will have a rather large impedance mismatch.

Remember that impedance largely depends on physical properties like size and distance (to each other and ground), so a "breakout" is never a good idea for any HF transmission lines.

The 6 MHz with USB Full devices may work in some cases with short cables, and some AVR programmers only use USB low speed anyway - those are less sensitive to this problem.